# Error while checking out project from source control in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, tfs

A coworker checked in an asp.net MVC project she was working on into subversioning and when I try to access it, it gives me an error. I looked at her PC and it looks to me like everything's checked in.

When she runs it on her pc it runs fine. When she publishes the site to our development server it also works.

If it means anything I'm using team foundation server as my subversioning, i'm running VS2010 and the project is in asp.net 4.0 and MVC 2.

The error I'm getting is..

Error   1   Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class  C:\websites\sandbox-workspace\admin\MVC\Models\JobRepository.cs 9   18  career-mvc

Line 9 looks like..
https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8aGb.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a TFS issue.  You are missing something on your development stack.  If I had to take a guess, it's probably either a missing class or you are missing the MVC DLLs.

If you would post what JobRepository.cs line 9 looks like, we might have a better capability to hep.

Comment: I posted a link to an image of line 9. I think your right about my project missing something. I don't see anything missing though.

Comment: That's weird.  You may want to look to see if there are any extension methods within that class (look for a method definition with "this" in the parameters).